# Rails: Find all X that are assigned to one Y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find

I'm new to rails, so please excuse me for that possibly very stupid question.

I have a model User and a model Experiment, both linked by a HABTM relationship.

When I want to display, let's say: `/experiments/1/users`, it shows me all usere there are, not filtered by the experiment. Okay, that's because of the `UsersController`.

In the `UsersController`, I therefore define:

```
# GET /users
# GET /experiment/:experiment_id/users
def index

  if (params[:experiment_id] == nil)
    @users = User.all
  else
    @users = # HOW DO I FIND THE USERS FOR THE EXP?
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
  end
end
```

I want to filter the users, but something like `User.find_all_by_experiment_id` does not exist: `undefined method`find_all_by_experiment_id' for #`

What can I use to get the users that are assigned to the current experiment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Experiment.find(params[:experiment_id]).users should work.

Comment: Perfect. I just didn't realize I could go the other way.

Answer (score 2):

First you should define in the Experiment model that it had more Users. I guess that there is 1-to-n or n-to-n relationship between Experiment and Users. This looks something like this:

```
class Expetiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
```

Then when you look up the Experiment in the experiment's controller by calling  `Experiment.find(params[:experiment_id])`, you can call its `users` method to get the list of users related to the experiment.